# Is Apple auto-renew subscription workflow exactly?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

There is my architect system about in app purchase feature.

[image]

My in app purchase includes the compoments such as:

**Client**: My mobile application.

**Server**: My server system.

**Apple's Store** : Apple's store that connect to iTunes connect configured to in app purchase.

**Hook statusUpdateNotification**: A *`statusUpdateNotification`* is a server-to-server notification service for auto-renewable subscriptions. A notification specifies the status of a subscription at the time the notification is sent. **reference link** : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6

**Database**: My database system.

***The current workflow***:

- **Step 1** : Mobile app request to payment to apple's store via `ios's Storekit` and user's ituneconnect when user buy an item in app.
- **Step 2(1)** : Apple's store charged for user if `product_id` match with store and return for mobile app a bill.
- **Step 3(1)** : Mobile app send this bill to server with authentication to server know who is buyer. Server will validate bill with apple's store by ***step 5(1)*** , if bill valid , apple's store will response result to notify that this bill valid *( **step 4(1)** )* and server will update this product for user, moreover ***server will store an unique `bill_id` and `user_id` to renewable next time***---------- ***step 6(1)***. And server will response for client to exit process ( ***step empty number*** ) => the first way to purchase success.

In solution this item is renewable , the system will use **Hook statusUpdateNotification** system.

- **Step 1** : The same action above.
- **Step 2(2)** : Apple's store will deliver JSON objects via an HTTP POST to your server for the key subscription events listed in [Table 6-3](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW15). ***My problem start at here.*** . Apple will send for hook with a `latest_receipt_info` and I can parsing to get `original_transaction_id`, but if just only have `original_transaction_id` , my system will can't know to update for someone, so I need to query from my database with `original_transaction_id` and get `user_id` stored ( **step 3(2)**) before ( ***step 3(1)*** if luckey *because if hook received receipt_info from apple before client send bill to server, I don't know this* `original_transaction_id` for `user_id`. )
- If Hook can get `user_id` from database with `original_transaction_id`, my purchase process will success. Otherwise my system will fail because I can't know user will be updated bought product.

I don't sure when apple's store will send bill to my client and when it will send to hook. It's suck.

**My question**: My solution is exactly?  Anyone have solution to improve this problem? thank you. Please provide request take clear information if you don't understand any my description.

Comment: Your server can effectively ignore `INITIAL_BUY` messages since you will receive subscription notification from your client that contains the receipt and your user id. For renewal events your server will know the user id

Comment: @Paulw11: Do you mean when an event `INITIAL_BUY` comes , basically my server wil ignore this message and apple will send bill to my client?

Comment: Yes, you could ignore it or you could save the receipt and wait for the message from your client 3(1) that will contain the same receipt and the user id

Comment: @Paulw11: I should put this apple's notify back my queue ( I use RabbitMQ such as a message broker ) or reject this message and remove out queue ?. Or back to queue to wait retry event execute ? :3

Comment: You can probably just discard it since you will get the message from your client App anyway